# Json to DateTime - change format

Tags: javascript, c#, json, datetime, date-format

I send from JS (with JSON) to server (C#) a string date in format "dd/mm/yyyy" - for example "23/10/2014", but C# DateTime gets null. If I send "10/23/2014" it works.
I use MVC4.

How can I change that format that DateTime gets to I'll be able to send "23/10/2014"?

Comment: How do you _send_ your `"23/10/2014"`? Can you show your code as well? We can't help you without see your work. A `DateTime` doesn't have any implicit format by the way.

Comment: To where and from where? Can you show some code that gives you null instead of expected value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question but I think you're safer to send the date as: **yyyy/mm/dd**

Then you don't need to worry about internationalisation. MVC will parse this correctly.

**EDIT**

Matt made a good comment below. The format of the date should be: **yyyy-mm-dd** which is in agreement with the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

Comment: Actually, you should use the [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format in JSON - `"2014-10-23"`.  Obligitory: http://xkcd.com/1179/

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the date format in the serialization settings

```
var jsonString = @"{'ID':'1','Date':'23/10/2014'}";

JsonSerializerSettings jSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    DateFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy"
};

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TheType>(jsonString, jSettings);
```

Comment: That works for Json.Net / Web API but not MVC.  MVC uses JavaScriptSerializer internally.